# One-word riddle (possibly python)

Tags: riddle, computer-puzzle

The question/riddle is: "Never has a snake given such words of wisdom."

The hint is: "Thou shall never pass errors silently!"

It is possible to be related to Python, errors or something like that. Any idea?

Comment: Could you please site the source, if any? Otherwise it may be closed. Thanks!

Comment: It's just a logic game in my university; it's not on any site.

Comment: That doesn't matter.  If you didn't create this puzzle, you must say who did (*in* the question body; not in a comment).

Answer (score 2):

> I think it's referencing [the Zen of Python](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zen_of_Python).

Comment: hello and welcome to PSE. Please hide your answers in spoilers.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's

> The [Hello World program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%22Hello,_World!%22_program).

Never has a snake given such words of wisdom.

> "Hello World" can be deep, like when the pandemic ends.

Thou shall never pass errors silently!

> It's really hard to mess up a Hello World program!